# implementing rhino security where user Id data type is not long

Tags: c#, rhino-security

i want to implement rhino security on my application. i have user entity class whose Id field is GUID.

according to Rhino security instructions i have to implement IUser interface which contains an id field which is long. now how can i implement IUSer interface without changing datatype of my user entity class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where'd you see that?  The IUser interface only requires implementors to expose a SecurityInfo property.

[IUser source](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-security/blob/master/Rhino.Security/IUser.cs)

I use Guids for my Ids and create a SecurityInfo object based on it

```
    public virtual SecurityInfo SecurityInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return new SecurityInfo(this.Username,this.Id);
        }
    }
```

The first argument is the name of the user (it can be any string property) the second is your id which can be any object, including Guids.